# How to use Arrow Meta with Android project

Tags: android, gradle, plugins

I try to create simple compiler plugin with Arrow Meta for Android application, base on example code. Problem is that usage with `XPlugin` parameter fails with compilation error

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
    freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xplugin=${project.rootDir}/plugin/core/build/libs/core-all.jar"]
}
```

```
e: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionsAreaImpl.getExtensionPoints()[Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/com/intellij/openapi/extensions/impl/ExtensionPointImpl;
```

Comment: Hi @bari! did you find any solution?

Comment: Apparently it has nothing to do with android applications but with the kotlin version you are using. Check this: https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow-meta/issues/554. As I am using 1.3.61-SNAPSHOT, I decided to downgrade to kotlin 1.3.61 and that issue dissapeared.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to use arrow meta in an Android project in the last weeks and fortunately I could make it work with the help of Arrow community.

Here you will find a [discussion](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow-meta/issues/738) on how to integrate arrow meta in an android project.

Here there is a link to a [repo](https://github.com/ocampoleandro/arrow-meta-android-example) where I use arrow meta. This is based in the latest [examples](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow-meta-examples) published by arrow community.

Basically, what you need to do is to create your plugin and something important to notice is the folder "create-plugin/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/". There you will have to create a file called "org.jetbrains.kotlin.compiler.plugin.ComponentRegistrar" where you need to declare your plugin.

Follow this [link](https://github.com/ocampoleandro/arrow-meta-android-example/blob/master/create-plugin/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.jetbrains.kotlin.compiler.plugin.ComponentRegistrar) in my repo.

Then you need to write the next lines in you app:build.grradle

```
android {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xplugin=${project.rootDir}/create-plugin/build/libs/create-plugin-all.jar"
    }
}
```

and

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ":create-plugin:createNewPlugin"
}
```

Then in your create-pluing:build.gradle add the next lines:

```
import java.nio.file.Paths

dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10"
    compileOnly "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:$kotlin_version"
    compileOnly "io.arrow-kt:compiler-plugin:1.4.10-SNAPSHOT"
}

// Create a new JAR with: Arrow Meta + new plugin
task createNewPlugin(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    archiveClassifier = "all"
    from 'build/classes/kotlin/main'
    from 'build/resources/main'
    from (
            zipTree(sourceSets.main.compileClasspath.find {
                it.absolutePath.contains(Paths.get("io.arrow-kt","compiler-plugin").toString())
            })
    ) {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/org.jetbrains.kotlin.compiler.plugin.ComponentRegistrar'
    }
}
```

It is important to notice that the kotlin version and the version of arrow meta are connected.

I use kotlin version 1.4.10 and arrow compiler plugin version 1.4.10-SNAPSHOT